# Copy datarow from relational database along with its relational data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2005\2008

Is there a way to copy a particular data row from one relation database to another similar database, along with its relational data? In a sense that all the other data (FKs) from this database which will need to be there for this particular data row to exist in destination database should also be copied.

I basically need to copy a particular scenario from the production box to test box, without copying the entire table \databases over to test systems.

I can definitely find all the Fk from this table and copy the data manually but that is too time consuming when the base tables keeps changing.

Any tool\ generic queries that can help me move a data scenario from one relational database to other.

Comment: Look at tools like [Red-Gate SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) or [Apex SQL Data Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_datadiff.aspx)

Comment: Looks like  Apex SQL Data will do what I need but I was looking for open source \ free solutions...

Comment: here is my attempt to solve this problem and open source it. Data Transfer Application (http://rdt.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my attempt to solve this problem and open source it.
[Data Transfer Application](http://rdt.codeplex.com)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services)](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/solutions-technologies/business-intelligence/integration-services.aspx) to transfer data from one database to another. It's scriptable and can be automated and scheduled if necessary.